# Convert this two line code to manipulate a DataGridView from .NET 3.5 to .NET 1.1

Tags: .net, winforms, datagrid, .net-1.1, c#-to-vb.net

I have this following C# code, written for .NET 3.5, and I want write this code in VB.NET, using version 1.1 of the framework.

I can convert C# to VB.NET, but I can't convert convert .NET 3.5 to .NET 1.1 because in .net 1.1 we don't have these properties: `RowCount`, `CurrentRow`, `Cells[index].value)`

Can someone please help me to convert this code?

```
if (DataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
{
    TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

I am asking not to advise me not to use .NET 1.1.

**EDIT**: Since I'm working with .NET 1.1 (using VB.NET), I have a GridView control. How can I access its cells, something like the C# code I show above

Comment: The problem is easily solvable... In .NET 1.1 you don't even have a DataGridView! It was introduced in .NET 2.0, so you can remove all the three lines :-)

Comment: why I must remove them? in .net1.1 we have DataGrid instead of DataGridView. So in DataGrid how I can use this code??

Comment: It was a joke... as Cody said, those three rows are probably a minimal part of your problem

Comment: @xanatos I changed my question, read again (the last line) and answer.

Answer (score 2):

The code cannot be converted to .NET 1.1. The problem is not simply a couple of missing properties, like `RowCount` and `CurrentRow`. The issue is much larger: the `DataGridView` control was not introduced until .NET 2.0. It is not available on older versions.

So there is no possible way to convert the code line-by-line. You'll need to change the whole design of the form, using a different control. That will require much more extensive changes to the code.

There *is* a [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) control way back in 1.1 (and it still exists today, but has been largely replaced by `DataGridView`). However, I have never used it and cannot provide any more helpful advice on how to use it to replace a `DataGridView`. There are [several important limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171628%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that you should be aware of.

Whether it is in C# or VB.NET makes no difference.

Comment: in .net1.1 we have DataGrid instead of DataGridView. So in DataGrid how can I store filelds of DataGrid in TextBox?

Comment: You named at least 2 controls I've never heard of. What is a GridView? And did you mean TextBox? It doesn't make any sense to display contents of a DataGrid in a TextBox. They are two completely different things. You'll need much more than a Stack Overflow question to convert a project using a DataGridView to a DataGrid.

Comment: I mean DataGrid, yes I mean TextBox... :D

Comment: I changed my question, read again (the last line) and answer.